# I have two columns, if one column has a certain word in a row, I'd like the other column to add 1 point to the corresponding row

Tags: r, conditional-formatting

I have a column with string values and a column with numeric values. I want to add to the numeric value of each row if the string column has a certain word in it

For example:

```
stringColumn  numericColumn 
----------------------------
yes            5
no             7
no             3
yes            4
```

The `numericColumn` already has random numbers in it, but after running the code it should add 1 point to the `numericColumn` if the `stringColumn = 'yes'`.

So the dataset would end up looking like this

```
stringColumn  numericColumn 
----------------------------
yes            6
no             7
no             3
yes            5
```

Comment: Look into `grepl()`, `mutate()`, and `ifelse()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the `numericColumn` by using an `ifelse` statement inside `mutate`. So, if `yes` is detected (via `str_detect`) in the `stringColumn`, then add 1 to the number in the `numericColumn` and if not (i.e., `no`), then just return `numericColumn`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(numericColumn = ifelse(
    str_detect(stringColumn, "yes"),
    numericColumn + 1,
    numericColumn
  ))
```

**Output**

```
  stringColumn numericColumn
1          yes             6
2           no             7
3           no             3
4          yes             5
```

Or in base R:

```
df$numericColumn <-
  ifelse(grepl("yes", df$stringColumn),
         df$numericColumn + 1,
         df$numericColumn)
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(stringColumn = c("yes", "no", "no", "yes"), numericColumn = c(5L, 
7L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways of getting to the answer you want, but here is my take on a `tidyverse` version. The conditional statements are made within `case_when()` that is used inside `mutate()`. It's worth reading into what `case_when()` does since it'll come in handy for various uses.

```
library(tidyverse)

example_df <- tibble(
  stringColumn = c("yes", "no", "no", "yes"),
  numericColumn = c(5,7,3,4)
)

results_table <- example_df %>%
  mutate(
    Updated_column = case_when(
      stringColumn == "yes" ~ numericColumn + 1,
      TRUE ~ numericColumn
    )
  )


# option 1: print to console 
results_table 

# option 1.2: a tidier way to view on the console
glimpse(results_table)

# option 2: view on RStudio 
View(results_table)

# option 3: save as file (eg. .csv format)
write_csv(results_table, "path/to/folder/my_results.csv")
```

Comment: that code worked but it put the answers in the console, the real dataset I'm working with has over 80 columns so it's hard to view it just in console form. is there a way to view it in table form?

Comment: @Avi A lot of people (including me) don't assign the output to a new variable in our answers. But I understand that the output in the console might not be the best when you apply it to your full dataset. You can always just assign the output to a new variable, then you can view output in the Rstudio Viewer. Or sometimes when I want to look at stuff quickly (and not create a new variable), then I just wrap `View()` around the whole function (e.g., `View(iris %>% select(1:2) %>% head())`.

Comment: My solution was just a sample for you to apply for your own dataset. If you want to save it you can either overwrite your existing variable or assign it to a new one. There are various ways to view data (eg. printing directly onto the console, `View()` as @AndrewGillreath-Brown suggested or exported it as a file. I'll update my answer so you can see this.